# Где можно брать новые знания для изучения пайтона?

Tags: python

А также где и как можно научиться

Comment: https://www.ozon.ru/product/python-sbornik-uprazhneniy-228562292/?sh=oNz-0xrqlw

Answer (score 0):

Лучше всего в книгах. Ввиду того, что их авторы стараются быть последовательны в изложении материала. Хорошо работает комбинация книг из одного справочника, двух-трех книг с практикой, и еще одной по мелким задачам, хукам, рецептам. Если книг будет недостаточно, то можно, для уверенного старта, сначала заниматься с репетитором.

Comment: Всё проще: нужен туториал, мануал, и пинок в самостоятельное плавание.